# Why do lower frequency EM waves behave so differently from light?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

EM waves include both lower frequency(RF/microwave/mm -wave) and higher frequency(visible light).

My question is: why do these waves, whos behavior is governed by the same maxwells euqations, behave so fundamentally differently?

For example, you can accurately understand a scene using a camera which has been designed to receive light waves. In particular you can create an array of photoreceptors where each sensor essentially gives you information only about a small FoV targeting a particular area it is pointed at. In addition the scattering effect of light waves is not significant - in general you pickup only the waves which are reflecting off that particular point.

On the otherhand RF environments are incredibly chaotic, it's essentially impossible to design an antenna with the same limited receptive FoV as a photo-receptor or accurately get information from a point target in a cluttered environment using RF signals.

Why is this? Why are light-waves so well behaved compared to RF waves?

Comment: have you heard of walabot and RF capture? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBFMsY5ZP0o

Answer (score 10):

This statement:

> On the otherhand RF environments are incredibly chaotic, it's essentially impossible to design an antenna with the same limited receptive FoV as a photo-receptor or accurately get information from a point target in a cluttered environment using RF signals.

isn't actually correct. It's fairly straightforward to design an antenna that accurately gets information from a point target in a cluttered RF environment. That antenna is called a radio telescope, and there are quite a few of them that exist.

The difference is that radio telescopes have to be **large** (a single "pixel" effectively takes an aperture on the order of meters in length) in order to get a good enough angular resolution to do anything with. Specifically, the problem is that **longer wavelengths diffract much more strongly** than shorter wavelengths. Diffraction limits the angular resolution $\Delta\theta$ of a sensor in a manner given by the *Rayleigh criterion*:

$$\sin(\Delta\theta)=1.22\frac{\lambda}{d}$$

for a sensor with a circular aperture. As you can see, if you want to observe a long wavelength, your radiation-collecting device had better be *larger* than the wavelength you're observing. Radio waves have wavelengths on the order of centimeters to meters, which means that you need at least that big of a dish to see a point source with any clarity. In contrast, visible light has wavelengths less than a micrometer, so your sensors can be quite small indeed without much penalty to resolution.

Comment: I looked up radio telescope but I didn't see a discussion on FoV, Discussion mostly focused on using parabolic reflectors to collect more of a signal. Could you explain in more detail how these are designed to be highly directive towards a small FoV?

Comment: @FourierFlux Radio telescopes only have one "pixel", so FoV is the same thing as angular resolution. The data it gives you is only a single number - the intensity of the signal when the telescope is pointed in a particular direction. This number corresponds to the integrated intensity of everything in the telescope's current FoV.

Comment: @FourierFlux If we could treat radio waves just as rays that reflect and refract while ignoring diffraction, then the field of view would only be related to the sensor diameter (not the dish diameter) and the dish focal length; in that universe, increasing the dish size would only increase the amount of radio signal collected without changing the field of view. But in our universe, we can't ignore diffraction. Waves effectively don't "see" things that are smaller than their wavelength, so the dish needs to be large enough for radio waves to "see" it and properly reflect.

Comment: Unless I am missing something there isn't a discussion on the ability of the antenna to filter out sources or localize. It's not clear why it can filter sources so only the wave coming from directly in front of it gets picked up or how this is related to wavelength.

Comment: @FourierFlux This is due to the geometry of a parabola. All outgoing rays emitted from the focal point of a parabola, no matter in which direction they're emitted, will travel in the exact same direction after reflection. Conversely, the _only_ incoming rays which will intersect the focal point after reflection are those which are coming from that specific direction. See the following for more details: http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph5B/parabolic09.pdf.

Comment: @FourierFlux So if you have a pointlike sensor exactly at the focal point, and if you ignore diffraction, you will only receive signals from one direction. For a sensor of finite size, you will also receive some signals that are deflected a bit from the axis of the parabola, and this determines the geometric component of the angular resolution. If you then account for diffraction, you'll also find that you're receiving signals from other directions as the waves bend around the various elements of your optical setup, which also worsens your angular resolution.

Comment: I don't disagree that parabolic dishes focus incoming rays onto a focal point, I'm not seeing a discussion on its ability to filter out waves which aren't perpendicular to the antenna(it still will collect RF waves from everywhere). I'm also not seeing how the localization is really comparable to what's achieved with a pixel sized sensor. The antenna FOV is still much, much greater than a photodiode. Basically I don't see much discussion dealing with localization resolution or why lower frequency RF waves can't be localized in the same way.

Comment: @FourierFlux If you look at the diagrams in the article I just linked, rays from other directions don't hit the focal point. If your sensor is at the focal point, then rays from other directions won't hit your sensor. They will generally intersect in a region that's not where your sensor is (and they won't all mutually intersect at the same point either, but rather in some spread-out blob; see the diagram labeled "coma").

Comment: @FourierFlux According to this datasheet, the FOV for a photodiode (specifically, an APD) is +-50 degrees: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/313/AD1500-10_TO_500883-586458.pdf. Meanwhile, a parabolic antenna with a diameter of 1 m, detecting radio waves with a wavelength of 1 cm, has an angular resolution (i.e. a single-pixel FOV) of +-0.7 degrees, by the Rayleigh criterion.

Comment: @FourierFlux Anyway, what specifically do you mean when you refer to "localization"?

Comment: Worth noting: the photoreceptors in our eyes are decidedly non-directional.  Their only directionality comes from the fact that there is a lens shaping the light beams, similar to how the parabolic mirror shapes them.

Comment: I'm talking about the integrated receptors used in cameras. By localization I'm talking about the ability for the antenna to only pick up radio waves being emitted by a single point source which may be close to another point source. EX: camera sensors pick up "pixels" localized to a fairly narrow FOV.

Comment: @FourierFlux The receptors themselves actually can accept light coming from a wide variety of directions, just like the APD above. The only reason that a camera has any kind of decent resolution is because the sensors are placed in a light-proof box, while light is only let in through a narrow aperture, and redirected using a system of lenses such that the only light that hits a particular sensor comes from a particular direction. It's the _lenses_ and narrow aperture that accomplish localization in a camera, not the sensors. Similarly, it's the parabolic dish that accomplishes localization.

Comment: I see on the lenses, I don't really think the dish accomplishes the same level of localization - for example if you place two RF transmitter in the same general area and point the parabolic antenna at such area, it  will pick them both up almost equally. If this wasn't the case you would see high resolution RF cameras but these don't exist. The few examples that are present take a bunch of signal processing to produce what we consider to be an image. But this does result in the question: why don't antennas use the same type of setup as cameras to localize RF sources?

Answer (score 3):

Lightwaves are just as "poorly" behaved, but on a different scale.  All of the effects you are interested in are proportional to wavelength.  A 400nm blue light source on our scale has the same behaviors as a 400kHz RF source has on a scale 1 million times larger!  If you had an antenna the size of the empire state building, you could resolve RF the same way we resolve IR.

Interestingly enough, we see these "poor" behaviors in light as well.  BluRay departed from the traditional red lasers because it was not possible to image the pits on the disc on the scale they needed.  Red light just wasn't good enough.  And there's talk that the next technology may have to move to UV lasers to increase density!

Comment: Could you explain why? Also photoreceptors appear to operate on a fundamentally different mechanism than classical electromagnetic antenna theory.

Comment: @FourierFlux The reason sensors in different regimes operate differently is because atoms have energy levels that are spaced apart by a certain energy (corresponding roughly to photons in the IR to UV range). So radiation in the IR to UV range begins to excite individual atoms or molecules instead of inducing motion in lots of free electrons (i.e. generating an electric current). The energy that this boundary exists at is determined by the fundamental strength of the electromagnetic force.

Comment: @FourierFlux In turn, photons with energy _higher_ than UV require a different sensor design as well. Now they are no longer stopped by most materials, so you can't really build reflectors that redirect them anymore.

Comment: @probably_someone What is the type of spectroscopy that describes this electromagnetic electron interaction? is it Impedance spectroscopy? I am familar with the usual https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhH8f.jpg rotational, vibrational, electron excitation spectroscopies but not antenna oscillation

Comment: @ChemEng The word *spectroscopy* , is derived from *spectrum*., individual lines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line . These only exist in *atomic dimensions*, i.e. wavelengths between ultraviolet and infrared. Electrons in antennas behave like free charged particles and emit photons in a continuum of energy.

Comment: @ChemEng In conductors, there are a large number of essentially-free electrons that have energies within a continuum that is usually called the "conduction band". Radio waves induce large-scale collective motion in the conduction band electrons. They don't really excite individual electrons, much like a water pump doesn't vibrate individual water molecules.

Comment: @FourierFlux The wavelengths of EM cover a huge range, and different scales require different physical oscillation processes. At visible & UV wavelengths the oscillators are atomic electron transitions, radio oscillations happen at a larger scale. Crudely speaking, you can't build a single atom with a 1 metre radius, and you can't build a radio antenna that's a few hundred nanometres long.

Comment: @annav yes but i believe spectroscopy also exists throughout the spectra take a look at radio astronomy and gamma spectrocopy. Also in MRI with high magnetic fields radiowaves are used. This is also possible at low magnetic fields take a look at zero field spectroscopy

Comment: @ChemEng in the article on radio astronomy the word "spectroscopy"  is missing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_astronomy . "Spectroscopy"  is used in physics to describe the study of the line spectra  afaik. Gamma spectroscopy has nothing to to do with atomic line spectra, it is nuclear energy levels way over even ultraviolet, at over kev energies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_spectroscopy